# Drag & Drop - Slide from a jTextPane white part?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, highlighting, jtextpane

if I Drag & Drop a selected text from a jTextPane to another window it work.

But is there a way to Drag & Drop the text from a jTextPane by **clicking-sliding Directly from the white part of a jTextPane area ?**
(mean whithout the need to click on a selected-highlighted text)

**OR auto-move the mouse pointer to the highlighted text ?**
(but appear to be a "less clean" solution : **is it the only solution ?**)

What I call "white part", is the area in jTextPane, where there is no highlighted text

Simple Example :

```
        /**
         * Basic Frame Settings
         */
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);

            JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
            textPane.setBounds(143, 73, 143, 78);
            contentPane.add(textPane);

            textPane.setEditable(false);
            textPane.setText("hello");
            textPane.setDragEnabled(true);
```

Selected text can be DnD

But how is it possible to DnD from the white area of the jTextPane ?

Comment: DnD works on `selected` text. If you click on a white part the selection is lost, so there is no text to drag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer : but is there a way to let DnD work from the white part of a jTextPane area ? :)

Comment: Could you provide SSCCE?

Comment: I didn't try it out, but theoretically you could autoselect all the text when clicking anywhere on text area, then start drag'n'drop.

Comment: **I search to make it user-friendly :)** it force to click on the selected text for DnD : in all the cases it force user to move the mouse pointer to the selected text and to click & slide : JTextPane space is reserved for itself, seem better to apply that on all over the JTextPane Box :) Please, have someone his own trick ?

Answer (score 0):

**Here a more clear Example to show a bit, how it is possible to do :**

```
                boolean b = true;

                setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
                contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                setContentPane(contentPane);
                contentPane.setLayout(null);

                final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

                textPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                        Robot robot = null;
                        try {
                            robot = new Robot();
                        } catch (AWTException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Testframe.class.getName()).log(
                                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                        // Set the Mouse X,Y Position
                        robot.mouseMove(textPane.getLocationOnScreen().x,
                                textPane.getLocationOnScreen().y);

                        if (b) {
                            // Simulate Mouse Double Click
                            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                            b = false;

                        }



                    }

                });

                textPane.setBounds(143, 73, 143, 78);
                contentPane.add(textPane);

                textPane.setEditable(false);
                textPane.setText("hello");
                textPane.setDragEnabled(true);
```

Does someone have another kind of better solution ??